# VBA Access Getting Runtime Error 3144 on previously working event

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I have an issue that has developed while modifying an update event that previously had been working. I am now getting a Runtime Error 3144, *"Syntax error in UPDATE statement."* When I go to debug the following line of code is flagged.
            Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strUpdate)

This function previously was working as it it was meant to in creating a SQL string to run an Update command. However I needed to adapt this same function to a different but mostly similar form.
I have included the complete code below for review and could use some assistance in spotting whatever little detail I missed/messed up in the transfer.

```
    Private Sub btnEntEdt_Click()
        Dim strUpdate As String
        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

        strUpdate = "UPDATE EntList AS e" & vbCrLf & _
                    "SET e.BusinessUnit = pBusinessUnit,  " & _
                    "e.EntityID = pEntityID, " & vbCrLf & _
                    "e.EntityName = pEntityName, " & vbCrLf & _
                    "e.Location = pLoc, " & vbCrLf & _
                    "e.Client = pCli, " & vbCrLf & _
                    "e.Dept = pDept, " & vbCrLf & _
                    "WHERE e.EntityID = pEntityID;"
        Debug.Print strUpdate

        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strUpdate)
        qdf.Parameters("pBusinessUnit") = Me.cboBUnit.Value
        qdf.Parameters("pEntityName") = Me.txtEntName.Value
        qdf.Parameters("pEntityID") = Me.txtEntID.Value
        qdf.Parameters("pLoc") = Me.cboLoc.Value
        qdf.Parameters("pCli") = Me.cboClient.Value
        qdf.Parameters("pDept") = Me.cboDept.Value
        qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
        Set qdf = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing

        Me.lstEntName.Requery

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were wise to include `Debug.Print strUpdate`.  Examine its output ...

```sql
UPDATE EntList AS e
SET e.BusinessUnit = pBusinessUnit,  e.EntityID = pEntityID, 
e.EntityName = pEntityName, 
e.Location = pLoc, 
e.Client = pCli, 
e.Dept = pDept, 
WHERE e.EntityID = pEntityID;
```

That statement triggers an error because of the comma at the end of the `SET` clause.

```
e.Dept = pDept, 
              ^ here
```

Eliminate that comma, test the revised `UPDATE` statement in the query designer, and once you have it working correctly, modify your VBA code to produce the same statement text.

Or you could save the working version as a named query, *qryUpdateEntList*, and then reference the named query from your VBA code instead of re-creating the statement text at run time.

```vb
Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qryUpdateEntList")
```

Apart from the syntax error, this combination looks wrong to me ...

```
SET e.EntityID = pEntityID
WHERE e.EntityID = pEntityID
```

Because of the `WHERE` clause, the `UPDATE` will only affect rows where `EntityID = pEntityID`.  So there is no need to `SET EntityID = pEntityID`; they are already equal.

Comment: Thank you, I found an additional issue that I had not accounted for as well. thank you for the assistance

Comment: You're welcome.  I just now added a note about `SET e.EntityID = pEntityID`.  I don't think it would break the `UPDATE`, but it's not useful either.